# How to display the typeface guidelines for a font in swift using UIViews?

Tags: ios, uiview, uifont

I am trying to visually depict the guides used in a font. This include the descender, ascender, median, baseline and capheight.

I am getting all the data using the font property of `majorLabel`. I have checked SO and have found something similar to mine concept from [Cocoanetics](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/02/understanding-uifont/) (Thanks SO for this).

```
// Labels
@IBOutlet weak var majorLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var minorLabel: UILabel!


// Font guide lines
@IBOutlet weak var ascender: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var capHeight: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var xHeight: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var baseLine: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var descender: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    /* This part sets up the baseline of two different fonts */
    majorLabel.sizeToFit()
    minorLabel.sizeToFit()

    var changedFrame = minorLabel.frame
    changedFrame.origin.y = CGFloat(ceilf(
        Float(majorLabel.frame.origin.y) + Float(majorLabel.font.ascender - minorLabel.font.ascender)

        ))
    minorLabel.frame = changedFrame


    //minorLabel.center.x = majorLabel.center.x


    //print(majorLabel.center.x)
    //print(minorLabel.center.x)

    /* This section handles about capturing the font specific properties. */
    //baseLine.frame.origin.y = changedFrame.origin.y

    let baseLineLocation = majorLabel.frame.origin.y + majorLabel.font.ascender
    let medianLocation = majorLabel.frame.origin.y + majorLabel.font.xHeight
    let capHeightLocation = baseLineLocation  - majorLabel.font.capHeight
    let descenderLocation = baseLineLocation - majorLabel.font.descender
    let ascenderLocation = baseLineLocation - majorLabel.font.ascender

    print("Ascender: \(majorLabel.font.ascender)")
    print("Cap height: \(majorLabel.font.capHeight)")
    print("Median: \(majorLabel.font.xHeight)")

    print("Descender: \(majorLabel.font.descender)")

    baseLine.frame.origin.y = baseLineLocation
    xHeight.frame.origin.y = medianLocation
    capHeight.frame.origin.y = capHeightLocation
    descender.frame.origin.y = descenderLocation
    ascender.frame.origin.y = ascenderLocation



}
```

In the above code the five UIViews have fullscreen width and height of just 1 to draw a small crisp line.

I would like to get a similar result as the image below to display the line.

[image: Typeface guidelines]

I am already getting proper results and would like it to be as accurate as possible. Is the code above is the proper way to render the lines?